# Trigger to populate Last Modified date on Content version?

Tags: trigger, contentversion

In the content version, there is a Last Modified Date that populates both the date and time, so I created a custom field called Last_Modified__c with a field type Date that is set to create only date not time.

Now I need a trigger that populates the last modified date, & not the time in Last_Modified__c based on the LastModifiedDate field in the content version.

```
trigger updateLastModifiedField on Last_Modified_Date__c (after insert) {
List<ContentVersion> LastModifiedToUpdate = new List<ContentVersion>();
for(Last_Modified_Date__c  cv: Trigger.new){
    if(nt.ParentId != null && nt.ParentId.getSObjectType() == schema.ContentVersion.sObjectType){
        ContentVersion cv=new ContentVersion(Id=cv.parentId,RecentNoteContent__c=cv.Body);
        LastModifiedToUpdate.add(cv);

   } 
}

if(!LastModifiedToUpdate.isEmpty()){
    update LastmodifiedToUpdate;
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? SFSE is not a code-writing service but can often help you with specific problems (see [ask]).

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that. It's hard to read code in comments (and the length of comments is very limiting). After you copy/paste your code into your question, click the `{}` button to format it so it shows up nicely.

Comment: Thank you for adding your code. We still don't know what your question is. Please [edit] the body of your post to give a detailed, specific statement of the issue and what you're asking the community.

Answer (score 0):

Your OP is confusing as the trigger isn't on ContentVersion so I'm assuming that is what you wanted based on your description

```
trigger updateLastModifiedField on ContentVersion (after insert) {
  List<ContentVersion> cvs = new List<ContentVersion>();
  for(ContentVersion  cv: Trigger.new){
    cvs.add(new ContentVersion (Id = cv.Id,
                                Last_Modified_Date__c = cv.LastModifiedDate.dateGMT()));
   } 

  update cvs; 

}
```